# ¿Cómo hacer un CASE WHEN en una subconsulta a una consulta en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una duda, estoy haciendo un `select` al cual le estoy aumentando  campo `cv`, para que la tabla se vea a la derecha y no se liste para abajo y mi consulta es que si el dato es `vacio o null` me salga `sin datos` y si tiene me salga `tiene datos`. Aquí les dejo el código:

```
SELECT CE.ID_ENTI,
 (SELECT TOP 1 case when PD.ID_PERS_DOCU is not null then 'Tiene datos'else 'no tiene datos' end FROM ENTITY..PERSON_DOCUMENTS PD WHERE PD.ID_PERS_ENTI =  PE.ID_PERS_ENTI AND PD.ID_TYPE_DOCU = 3) [CV]

  FROM Entity..PERSON_DOCUMENTS PD
```

Pero me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo haría para poder solucionarlo? puede ser de cualquier manera, desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Es complicado responder, cuando la consulta que muestras es incorrecta, porque no puede dar resultados, ya que CE.ID_ENTI se refiere a un conjunto que la consulta no tiene.

Por otro lado, no tiene sentido a priori hacer una subconsulta en una columna, para algo que ya tienes, porque el conjunto `PERSON_DOCUMENTS`, ya lo dispones.

La columna actual que muestras te devuelve null porque ningún resultado de esa consulta para esa fila, resuelve resultados, ya que le has añadido un predicado  `WHERE PD.ID_PERS_ENTI =  PE.ID_PERS_ENTI AND PD.ID_TYPE_DOCU = 3`. Si esa causísitica no existe no hay un Top (1) y entonces es `Null`.

Case permite usar lógica, por tanto puedes añadir más expresiones.

```
SELECT CE.ID_ENTI, -- desconocido
 CASE WHEN PD.ID_PERS_DOCU is not null AND PD.ID_TYPE_DOCU = 3
            then 'Tiene datos'
            else 'no tiene datos' 
        end AS DATOS

  FROM Entity..PERSON_DOCUMENTS PD ;
```

Si necesitas una respuesta mejor, tendrás que elaborar una pregunta mucho mejor.